# Logic behind addition of two intervals

Tags: interval-arithmetic

I would like to know the logic behind adding two intervals $$[a, b]$$ $$[c, d]$$ together and for the sake of simplicity let's say that the numbers in the interval are just integers and not real numbers. I know that the idea is to just add the lowest and highest of the two $$[a+c, b+d]$$ and this is the result of the addition.

My question is whether this is just defined to be like this mathematically or is there a real world example that can shed some light on why it is calculated so?

Comment: This is simply a consequence of adding linear inequalities.

Comment: Suppose we know that a < x < b, and c < x < d.  Then (a + c) < x <  (b + d).  Thus, ([a, b] + [c, d]) = [(a + c), (b + d)].

Comment: @Doug, that shows $[a,b]+[c,d]$ is contained in $[a+c,b+d]$, but you need something more to show they're equal.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're right.  Oops.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - Did you mean "$a \le x \le b$ and $c \le y \le d$. Then $(a+c) \le x + y \le (b+d)$"? Without $x + y$, what you wrote has far more wrong than Gerry Myerson pointed out. (And of course $[\;,\;]$ mean $\le$, not $<$.)

Comment: @Paul I was also very confused by Doug's comment.

Comment: They were just expanding on Deepak's comment. When $A, B$ are sets of numbers, $A+B$ most commonly means the set $A + B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$. If $A, B$ are intervals, the fact that if $u \le v, x \le y$, then $u + x \le x + y$, a basic result about inequalities and addition, implies the double-sided inequality I gave, which gives $[a,b] + [c,d] \subseteq [a+c, b+d]$. On the other hand, suppose $z \in [a+c, b+d]$. Choose some $x \in [a,b]$ and consider $y = z - x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair you're right.  That's another error in there.

Comment: @Paul, if you choose the wrong $x$ in $[a,b]$ then $z-x$ won't be in $[c,d]$.

Comment: "The most common use is in software, to keep track of rounding errors in calculations and of uncertainties in the knowledge of the exact values of physical and technical parameters. The latter often arise from measurement errors and tolerances for components or due to limits on computational accuracy. Interval arithmetic also helps find guaranteed solutions to equations (such as differential equations) and optimization problems. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic

Comment: Have your questions been answered now, Michael? or is there still something you'd like to have clarified?

Comment: Earth to Michael: come in, please.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time till weekend to study this. On the first glance I think everything is covered for now.

Comment: OK. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment addressed to me, you have to put @Gerry in it, so I get notified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof that if $r$ is in $[a+c,b+d]$ then $r=x+y$ for some $x$ in $[a,b]$ and some $y$ in $[c,d]$:

First, note that $a+c\le r\le a+d$ or $a+d\le r\le b+d$.

In the former case, there must be $y$ in $[c,d]$ such that $r=a+y$. Let $x=a$.

In the latter case, there must be $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $r=x+d$. Let $y=d$.

Note: I'm not sure that this engages with OP's concerns. And I suspect that what I've written here has been written before on this site, probably multiple times. But it does seem to speak to some of the comments on the question.

Comment: Sure you don't have some typos here? For example $a+c \le r \le a + d$? How can this be in all cases?

Comment: I didn't say it was true in all cases. I wrote $a+c\le r\le a+d$ **OR** $a+d\le r\le b+d$.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the comments (nor the single answer) provide a "real world example" as the question wanted, I wanted to provide a simple one.

Let's say you are going to buy some apples from two stores. Store X will give you a minimum of $a$ apples, and a maximum of $b$ apples, thus its range is $[a, b]$. Meanwhile, store Y will give you a minimum of $c$ apples and a maximum of $d$ apples, thus its range is $[c, d]$.

In the worst case scenario, both stores will give you their minimum amount of apples. That would be $a$ apples from store X and $c$ apples from store Y. And in the best case scenario, they give you $b$ and $d$ apples, respectively. Thus, the new range that represents the sum of the number of apples that you can get from the two stores would be $[a+c, b+d]$.